# Magento2 How to show categories of product when product is opened from search bar?

Tags: magento2

Magento2 How to show categories of product when product is opened from search bar?
i want to load all parent categories id of product that i want to open from direct search bar not from menu.

Comment: by default when i opened any product from search bar it not save its parent categories ids i want to save its all category ids when i opened product from search bar

Comment: Where do you want these categories? On breadcrumb?

Comment: yes or its hidden no issue but it get all its parent categories id when i will search product from search bar and opened it.

Comment: i have to add some filter using product parent categories ids. when product opened from search bar

Comment: i have get a current category of product now i want to get parent categories of current category

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: yes i have resolved it

Answer (score 0):

You can get category collection from current product using this:

```
$product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
$categoryCollection = clone $product->getCategoryCollection();
```

If you are using Magento 2.3+ then registry wont work for you, in that case you need to get current product id by this:

```
$this->request->getParam('product_id');
```

where `$this->request` is the instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface`. You can load your product by `product_id`

where $this->registry is a instance of `Magento\Framework\Registry`

If you want tree level structure for breadcrumb, then you need to understand that product might be attached to multiple categories. So the best way to get proper categories tree is by getting product from highest level, like this:

```
    $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    $categoryCollection = clone $product->getCategoryCollection();
    $categoryCollection->clear();
    $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSort('level', $categoryCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/" . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() . "/%"));
    $categoryCollection->setPageSize(1);
    $currentTree = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getParentCategories();
    foreach ($currentTree as $category) {
        echo $category->getName()."<br>";
        echo $category->getUrl()."<br>";
    }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: i want without registry

Comment: Answer updated, please check